Finding a probability density function for $Z$ where $Z = XY$
Problem:
Let
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
 1 \,\, \text{for 0 $ \leq $ x $ \leq$ 1},\,\,\, \text{0 $ \leq $ y $ \leq$ 1} \\
 0,  \text{ elsewhere }
\end{cases}
$$
be a joint density function of $X$ and $Y$. Find the density function of
$Z = XY$
Answer:
The first step in the problem is to find the distribution function for $Z$. Note that
if we have $xy \leq z_0$ then we have $y \leq (z_ox)^{-1}$.
\begin{align*}
P( Z \leq z_0) &= \int_0^1 \int_0^{(z_0 x)^{-1}} \,\, dy \,\, dx \\
P( Z \leq z_0) &= \int_0^1 (z_0 x)^{-1} \,\, dx \\
P( Z \leq z_0) &= \dfrac{\ln{x}}{z_0} \Bigg|_{0}^1
\end{align*}
Now I have a problem because $\ln{0}$ is undefined and:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ln{x} $$
is not defined. Hence I am stuck.
The book's answer is:
$$ g(z) = \begin{cases}
 - \ln z, \,\,\,\, \text{for 0 $ < $ z $ < 1$ } \\
 0,\quad \quad \text{ elsewhere }
\end{cases} $$

We have the following:
$$
   \mathbb{P}(Z \le z_0) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 1\{xy \le z_0\}dydx
$$
and so, if $z_0 \le 0$ then $\mathbb{P}(Z \le z_0) = 0$ and if $z_0 \ge 1$, then $\mathbb{P}(Z \le z_0) = 1$.
Now, for $z_0 \in (0, 1)$, we split the double integral into two as follows:
$$
   \begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(Z \le z_0) &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 1\left\{y \le \dfrac{z_0}{x}\right\}dydx\\
     &= \int_0^{z_0}\int_0^1 1\left\{y \le \dfrac{z_0}{x}\right\}dydx + \int_{z_0}^1 \int_0^1 1\left\{y \le \dfrac{z_0}{x}\right\}dydx
   \end{align*}
$$
Consider the first integral, we integrate on the domain $(0, z_0] \times [0, 1]$, and in this domain, $\dfrac{z_0}{x} \ge 1 \ge y \ \forall y \in [0, 1]$, thus
$$
    \int_0^{z_0}\int_0^1 1\left\{y \le \dfrac{z_0}{x}\right\}dydx = \int_0^{z_0}\int_0^1 dy dx = z_0
$$
For the second integral, we integrate on the domain $(z_0, 1] \times [0, 1]$, and here $0 < \dfrac{z_0}{x} < 1$, so
$$
    \int_{z_0}^1 \int_0^1 1\left\{y \le \dfrac{z_0}{x}\right\}dydx = \int_{z_0}^1 \int_0^{z_0/x}dydx = \int_{z_0}^1 \dfrac{z_0}{x}dx = -z_0 \ln z_0
$$
Thus,
$$
    \mathbb{P}(Z \le z_0) = \begin{cases} 0, \text{ if } z_0 \le 0, \\ z_0 - z_0\ln z_0, \text{ if } z_0 \in (0, 1), \\ 1 \text{, otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
Taking derivative to get the density:
$$
  f_Z(z) = (-\ln z) \cdot 1_{(0, 1)}(z)
$$

I do not understand your third equation. That is, the equation after the statement: The inner integral can  be computed as. I suspect your  notion is what I do not understand. Could you write the inner integral as the sum of two integrals without the min function?

@Bob I've updated my answer

I am sorry but I still did not understand your use of the curly braces. Please tell me what it means or even better could you solve the problem without using the braces.

@Bob it is an indicator, equaling $1$ when the condition is met, and $0$ otherwise: $$1{xy\leq z_0}=\begin{cases}1&:& xy\leq z_0\0&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
